# break condition in if condition in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe, break

I'm trying to search a word from the text that I extract from the pdf file which is OCR'd format. This pdf file has multiple pages, so for each page I'm searching a word, if that word in found then I don't want the for loop to continue, I used the code but it just stop on first page. what m I missing in this code.
here is the code

```
for(i in 1:8){
  img_file <- pdftools::pdf_convert("D:/Files_OCR/test.pdf", format = 'tiff', pages = i, dpi = 400)
  text <- ocr(img_file)
  ocr_text <- capture.output(cat(text))
  check=sapply(ocr_text, paste0, collapse="")
  if(length(which(stri_detect_fixed(tolower(check),tolower("school")))) <= 0){ print("Not Present") } else {print("Present")}
  if(br=="present")
break

}
```

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: This works with the example below: `for(i in ssss) {if(i == "helo") break; print(i)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stopifnot` is the function - coupling this with `grepl` should help you break the loop

```
> ssss <- c('hi','helo','confusion','india')
> ssss
[1] "hi"        "helo"      "confusion" "india"    
> for(n in ssss){stopifnot(grepl('confusion',n)); print(n)}
Error: grepl("confusion", n) is not TRUE
> ssss[1] <- 'confusion'
> for(n in ssss){stopifnot(grepl('confusion',n)); print(n)}
[1] "confusion"
Error: grepl("confusion", n) is not TRUE
>
```